# My shapes from Visual Studio 2010/2012 Visual Basic PowerPack are missing in Visual Studio 2013, 2015 and 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to upgrade an old Windows Forms application, originally written in Visual Studio 2010. The solution uses Visual Basic Powerpack to have shapes (mainly circles) drawn on the screen. When I open the solution in VS 2010 or 2012 the shapes are visible. However when I open the same solution file with VS 2013, 2015 or 2017, they are no long there. I can add new shapes, but I'd rather not spend the time. Does anyone know of a fix for this? Please see attached screen shots.

[Visual Studio 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPTC4.png)
[Visual Studio 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npp6E.png)
[Visual Studio 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Qhb.png)
[Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3SR4.png)
[Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP2be.png)